# Backpropagation - computing partial derivative with respect to W

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am following a chapter on backprop derivation from the online book [by Michael Nielsen](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#eqtnBP4)

In particular, following equation is derived in Chapter 2:

${∂C\over∂w^{l}_{jk}}=a^{l−1}_{k}δ^{l}_{j}$

Now, I am trying to implement this in a vector form. I assume that proper operation is the outer product of vectors:

${{∂C\over∂w^{l}} =a^{l-1} \odot   (δ^{l})^T}$ (Correct me if I am wrong here)

Still, I often see on many sources that this equation is written as:

${{∂C\over∂w^{l}} =a^{l-1}δ^{l}}$

Am I missing something or this is just a different style of notation?

Comment: What do you mean by outer product? (Just to be sure)

Comment: @madhatter, according to definition - [Outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late response but I hope it may help:

### Important clarifications

First, we have to realize that the multiplication $a^{l-1}\delta^l$ as it appears in the question can't happen. This is because:

- $a^{l-1}$ is a $K\times 1$ vector that contains the activations of the layer $l-1$.
- $\delta^l\,\,\,\,\,\,$ is a $J\times 1$ vector that contains the "error" terms, $\partial C/\partial z^l$ of each neuron of layer $l$.

Where $K$ and $J$ are the total number of neurons in layer $l-1$ and $l$ respectively.

So the correct equation that we have to proof to be true is instead:
$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l}=\delta^l(a^{l-1})^T$$

With this said, we can also realize that the equation proposed in the question:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l}=a^{l-1}\odot (\delta^l)^T$$

can't be true, because the outer product (or Hadamard product as Michael Nielsen refers to it in the book): $\odot$, represents an element-wise multiplication between the terms $a^{l-1}$ and $(\delta^l)^T$. So unless these terms were both scalars ($J=K=1$) we would be unable to apply this element-wise multiplication.

---

### Reasoning using dimensionality of the weight matrix

Now the question that remains is: **Why is $\delta^l(a^{l-1})^T$ the correct equation**?. This is because all the weights of each layer $l$ are stored in matrix. This matrix is given by:

$$ w^l=W^l=
\begin{pmatrix}
    w_{11}^l & w_{12}^l & \cdots & w_{1K}^l\\
    w_{21}^l & w_{22}^l & \cdots & w_{2K}^l\\
    \vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots\\
    w_{J1}^l & w_{J2}^l & \cdots & w_{JK}^l\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where each entry $w^l_{jk}$ corresponds to the weight that connects the neuron $k$ of layer $l-1$ with the neuron $j$ of layer $l$.

So now we can intuitively see that $\partial C/\partial W^l$ should be of size $J\times K$ (size of $W^l$). Something that can be accomplished using $\partial C/\partial W^l= \delta^l(a^{l-1})^T$.

With this, if we wanted, we would be able to make the correct updates ($\Delta W^l$) on the weights using simple gradient descent (and other types of optimization, of course):
$$ W^l_{n+1} = \underbrace{W^l_n}_{J\times K} - \alpha \underbrace{\Delta W^l}_{J\times K} = W^l_n - \alpha \underbrace{\left( \delta^l(a^{l-1})^T \right)}_{J\times K}$$

Where $\alpha$ is the learning rate.

---

### A more correct reasoning (using the previous one)

To answer this more properly, we can realize that each element at location $(j,k)$ of the matrix $\Delta W^l$ is given by:

$$\Delta W_{(j,k)}^l=\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l_{jk}}=\delta^l_j a^{l-1}_k$$

So we can write $\Delta W^l$ as:

$$
\Delta W^l=
\begin{pmatrix}
    \delta^l_1 a^{l-1}_1 & \delta^l_1 a^{l-1}_2 & \cdots & \delta^l_1 a^{l-1}_K\\
    \delta^l_2 a^{l-1}_1 & \delta^l_2 a^{l-1}_2 & \cdots & \delta^l_2 a^{l-1}_K\\
    \vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \delta^l_J a^{l-1}_1 & \delta^l_J a^{l-1}_2 & \cdots & \delta^l_J a^{l-1}_K\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Which is the same as computing: $\delta^l(a^{l-1})^T$**

Comment: Outer product ([Wiki link from OP's comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)) is not the same thing as the Hadamard / elementwise product $\odot$, but rather $\otimes \colon (u,v) \mapsto u \otimes v = u v^{\mkern-1.5mu\mathsf{T}}$, resulting in a matrix. In particular $\delta^l \otimes a^{l-1} = \delta^l (a^{l-1})^{\mkern-1.5mu\mathsf{T}}$ is a valid way to write $\partial C / \partial W^l$. (Unfortunate that OP mixed up the two notationally)

Comment: @epimorphic, thank you, that's completely true and I believe that your point leads to more clarity. Looking back, I think that I stuck with the Hadamard product when answering because the book referenced by the OP uses $\odot$ to denote it.